# I am lauching an openGL program exe file from visual basic, But the texture is missing. What is wrong?

Tags: vb.net, path, textures, exe

The line to launch the exe is :

```
Shell("""D:\glut\SB5\VisualStudio2008\Chapter06\TexturedTriangle\TexturedTriangle.exe"" """ & lat & " " & lng, vbNormalFocus)
```

And the texture is present at the same path in the function parameter.
I see only a triangle without any texture on executing the exe from output of vb code

also it says

The shader at TexturedIdentity.vp could not be found.
while the file is at the same path

What could be wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shell command will launch an application with current process directory instead of your target exe directory.

To solve your problem: try to use System.Diagnostics.Process:

```
Dim exePath As String = "D:\parent\child\TexturedTriangle.exe"

Dim info As New ProcessStartInfo(exePath ) 
info.WorkingDirectory = IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(exePath)
info.Arguments = lat & " " & lng
Process.Start(info)
```